# Element that automatically toggles with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an element that toggles by itself. For a example, I want `<p>Text1</p>` to switch to `<p>Text2</p>` in 1 second. Is there any javascript code I can use?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

[Text-toggling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1YTA.gif)

Comment: Have you tried setInterval or setTimeout?

Comment: Do you need it to toggle repeatedly, from 1 to 2 to 1 to 2 etc, or just once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the setTimeout(//function,n*1000) function in order for it to be done automatically after n seconds

With your example lets say you have:

```js
let s = 1000; // second in milliseconds
let n = 3; //let's say you want it to change after 3 seconds

function changeText() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerText = 'Text2'
}

setTimeout(() => {
  changeText()
}, n * s); // you could also use setTimeout(function () { changeText() }, n * s);
```

```html
<p id="text">Text1</p>
<!-- give the element an id ("text") in this example -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a class or an ID to element, eg. `<p id="el">...</p>`, so that you can query it later on. Then, get it via [`document.getElementById`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) or [`document.getElementByClassName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp): `document.getElementById('el')`.

Now you got the element, time to change the text inside it, so access it via the innerText property, then assign a new value.

Alright, you want it to do it in one second, so set a timeout:

```js
setTimeout(() => { /** ... */ }, 1000);
```

Note: 1000 is 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to assign each element an id.  Then in javascript, call `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.  Every second, get the documents by id and toggle their CSS visibility style.